# TableCell Texts inside Card Is Overflowing in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a table inside a table card and i have a problem on its TableCell. If the word is too long it is overflowing horizontally. How would i break it to the next line? Pls see the "code" there because its overflowing

Pls see my codesandbox here   [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/card-twxzb?file=/demo.js)

```
        <TableBody>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell variant="head">Date</TableCell>
            <TableCell variant="body">{order.date}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell variant="head">Code</TableCell>
            <TableCell variant="body">{order.code}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell variant="head">Time</TableCell>
            <TableCell variant="body">{order.time}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell variant="head">Product</TableCell>
            <TableCell variant="body">{order.product}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `word-break: break-word`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  wrapTableCell: {
    wordBreak: "break-word"
  }
});

<TableCell
  classes={{ root: classes.wrapTableCell }}
  variant="body"
>
  {order.code}
</TableCell>
```

[image: Edit Card (forked)]